# Explicit Conversion to IDisposable

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable, explicit-implementation

I am using some `XmlReader` and `XmlWriter` object to do some needed work on strings inside some `try...catch` blocks.

I know that using the notation `using (XmlReader NewReader = XmlReader.Create(...))` is the prefered syntax, but I don't really like that so I am also appending `finally` blocks and executing `NewReader.Close();` and `NewWriter.Close();`.

However, *code analysis* is complaining that these objects aren't being disposed, thus forcing me to somehow call `Dispose()` method.

The problem is that in these classes the `Dispose()` method is implemented explicitly, so I have to use `((IDisposable)(NewReader)).Dispose();` and `((IDisposable)(NewWriter)).Dispose();`.

Are there any drawbacks to this technique?

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use the using statement. It does everything you need to do, you won't get the fxcop warning *and* it's more concise than using try-finally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# `using` statement will always call `Dispose` for you. It roughtly translates to the following:

```
XmlReader NewReader = XmlReader.Create(...);
try
{
   // do stuff on NewReader 
}
finally
{
    ((IDisposable)NewReader).Dispose();
}
```

So wrapping it in `finally` youself doesn't add any value. Although `Close` and `Dispose` are often equivalent, it is not always the case. Because of this FxCop is right, you should always call `Dispose` and when you do this (or let the `using` statement do this), there is no reason to call `Close` manually.

Answer (score 4):

There are good reasons for not using `using`:

- When the lifetime of the object might need to survive longer than the current block

and there are poor reasons for avoiding `using`:

- "I don't really like that"

Does the good reason apply to your code?

Please also note that a simple extension method would make the syntax nice and clean again.

Answer (score 1):

The `using` statement is really the preferred solution. It's idiomatic in C#. These classes implement `IDisposable` explicitly because they already provide a method that has closing semantics: `Close`. My bet is that `Dispose` calls `Close`, or vice-versa. *But you shouldn't count on that, and should always call `Dispose` anyway.*

In the end, all these are equivalent:

1. Use `using`, which is preferred;
2. <s>Call `Close` on the `finally` block, and suppress the static analysis warnings or;</s>
3. Call `Dispose` on the `finally`: `((IDisposable)NewReader).Dispose();`

Comment: Unfortunately, `Close` and `Dispose` do not always behave the same. Besides the obvious difference that closed instances can often be reopened, while disposed instances can’t, some objects don't suppress finalization when calling `Close` (such as the `SqlConnection`) which forces you to call `Dispose` anyway to prevent extra pressure on the GC.